# Need lightweight issue tracker for project

Tags: agile, scrum, agile-project-management

I need a lightweight issue tracker for a new project, with about 5 people on the project. Any recommendation? I read the two other threads on that topic, but it didn't seem satisfactory. I don't need to integrate with git. I just need something super simple, and very, very easy to setup, like a scrum board in the computer (other teams here have physical scream boards). I'm about to roll out an Excel spreadsheet in a shared directory on my Linux box...

Comment: Trello works perfectly :) You can try JIRA ([http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview)) with/or GreenHopper ([http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview))

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem. What is the underlying process issue that you believe a "lightweight issue tracker" will solve for you? You'd probably get better answers by reframing this as a process question.

Comment: In the future you can take a look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for issue tracker suggestions. Personally I use http://www.asitrack.com, but there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend a github account.  Make a repo there and track issues using the native github issues that come with each git repository.  Then use www.huboard.com to add an extremely lightweight agile/kanban view of your issues.  It's easy to set up, but works well.  Very simple and lightweight, and you can customize your kanban board view in huboard easily.

If you have a .edu email address github is free, and if not you can get an account that supports five commiters for only $7/month.  Well worth it for the awesome infrastrucure.

Answer (score 0):

Jira is nice, but it costs a little bit of money. If you're cash-strapped, you may want to consider Trac. It provides a lot of the same functionality as Jira, but there is no cost associated with it. However, if you decide you want to use a plugin to specifically track your project using Scrum and Kanban, then for your team size Jira/Greenhopper will be much less expensive than the Trac/Agilo combination.  Additionally, the Jira University has a number of online-courses on how to use Jira and the Greenhopper plugin that is very inexpensive.